# Checkbox doesn't appear on the UI , when dynamically created in grid using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, dynamic, asmx

Im totally new to vb , so please help me with the problem.

I have created a checkbox dynamically , and added in the gridview like below , I'm able to create a new column 'To Approve' while the rows has to have checkbox , but that does not appear. While debugging i can see that a new column is been created in the line 'resp.Columns.Add(column) ', but in UI it shows as a simple plain text field instead of checkbox.
Please let me know, whether the control used for checkbox is correct in the line 'newField.Control = "checkbox"  and  newField.Type = "CHKBOOLEAN"   ' Please help me with this.

```
    Dim ToAppCol As New CheckBox()    
    ToAppCol.Name = "toapprove"    
    ToAppCol.Checked = False    
    ToAppCol.Enabled = True    
    ToAppCol.Text = "To Approve"    
    ToAppCol.Width = "100"    

    Dim newField As GridFieldInfo    
    newField.Name = ToAppCol.Name    
    newField.Label = ToAppCol.Text    
    newField.Width = ToAppCol.Width    
    newField.Control = "checkbox"    
    newField.Type = "CHKBOOLEAN"    
    newField.Visible = True    
    'newField.Order = 1 ' though order gave as 1 , still didnot work.    
    grdData.Fields.Add(newField)   

    For Each ss As GridFieldInfo In grdData.Fields    
        If (ss.Visible) Then    
            Dim column As New Column    
            column.id = ss.Name    
            column.title = ss.Label    
            column.width = ss.Width    
            column.control = ss.Control    
            column.dataType = ss.Type    
            resp.Columns.Add(column)    
        End If    
    Next
```

Regards

Comment: Can you add a tag for the platform (WPF, WinForms, ASP.Net) please? And, also tag/mention any other UI technology you are using as well/

Comment: I don't see where `ToAppCol` is ever added to a form or grid.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only possible solution to this problem is that the GridFieldInfo shows a text field by default .
I'm not pratic with asmx , but , if you have it in your framework , you can use the **[DataGridViewCheckBoxCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcell?view=net-5.0)** object and add it to the columns directly . I Hope i understand correctly